# Next Occurrence of Time SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, datetime, time

Is it possible in any DBMS (Preferably MySQL or PostgreSQL) to have a column which always refers to the next date of the occurrence of a particular time? For example storing a time 02:00 would give the next datetime of occurrence 02:00.

This is needed in a bus timetabling scenario (with a fixed timetable) where the time of the next bus needs to be queried easily. This would be done by something like `where time > NOW() order by time asc`. However this would not work in a case such as querying at 23:00 for a next bus after midnight.

A solution I thought of (without dealing with it in a programming language) is to create a view with a conditional select column, something like `select if date(time) < now then date(time) + 24 hours else date(time)`

Answer (score 4):

Example data:

```
create table timetable (id int, dep_time time);
insert into timetable values
(1, '1:00'),
(2, '7:00'),
(3, '13:00'),
(4, '19:00'),
(5, '23:00');
```

The query executed around 22:00 (results depend on the time of the query execution):

```
select *,
    case when dep_time < current_time 
        then current_date+ 1+ dep_time
        else current_date+ dep_time
    end dep_datetime
from timetable 
order by 3;

 id | dep_time |    dep_datetime     
----+----------+---------------------
  5 | 23:00:00 | 2016-02-01 23:00:00
  1 | 01:00:00 | 2016-02-02 01:00:00
  2 | 07:00:00 | 2016-02-02 07:00:00
  3 | 13:00:00 | 2016-02-02 13:00:00
  4 | 19:00:00 | 2016-02-02 19:00:00
(5 rows)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=51333bb9259c9536fa4a47ab38d2d1f7)

In MySql the query may look like this:

```
select *,
    case when dep_time < current_time
        then current_date+ interval time_to_sec(dep_time) second+ interval 1 day
        else current_date+ interval time_to_sec(dep_time) second
    end dep_datetime
from timetable 
order by 3;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b7966ff68403568f7807e35276f8b29)